# Why doesn't my program work after I install it from a set-up file? (Server instance issues? I'm not sure)

Tags: c#, t-sql

When I build a set-up project for any app I make, even a simple one, it doesn't work after installing it.

I have the latest .Net framework installed and SQL Express is running.

The application gets the connection string from the app.config where I set it to the instance of the sqlexpress.

I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can I not access the SQLEXPRESS server from Visual Studio's Server Explorer?

I'm also not sure about the login for SQLEXPRESS.

I have tried using different server names and even rewriting the connection string to the actual path where the program installs.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|\appDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

I get the error trying to run this on visual studio if I keep the server name as SQLEXPRESS and not the default MSSQL name when I make the service-based database:

> 'Cannot open database "|DataDirectory|\appDB.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-#####'

Comment: It looks like the user doesn't have access i. the mdf database. You could make a specific username and password and put that in the connection string, or change chunks of the database to allow anonymous access.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I don't get how it works as a .exe file from the debug folder, but not when installed from the set-up, though. Any ideas as to why?